# Hard power series problem

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series

> Consider the differential equation $$(1+t)y''+2y=0$$
> with the variabel coefficient $(1+t)$, with $t\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Set $y(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n$. What are the first 4 terms in the associated power series?
>
> [image]

### An Attempt

We write
$$(1+t)y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nn(n-1)t^{n-2}+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nn(n-1)t^{n-1}$$
$$2y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2a_nt^{n} $$

Combining these three gives us

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nn(n-1)t^{n-2}+ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nn(n-1)t^{n-1}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2a_nt^{n}$$

We now want all the powers to be $t^n$.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)t^{n}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n+1}(n+1)nt^{n}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2a_nt^{n} $$

We finally want the index of summation to all be the same.
$$2a_0+2a_2+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)t^{n}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n+1}(n+1)nt^{n}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2a_nt^{n}$$

Which simplifies to
$$2a_0+2a_2+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\big[a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)+a_{n+1}n(n+1)+2a_n \big]t^n$$

Clearly, I'm not getting anywhere close to any of the answers given. I just can't find what I'm doing wrong. I have also tried with Maple, but that didn't give me any real result either.

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: $b$ is the correct answer, assuming that $y(0) = 0$. It looks like the more general class of solutions is not an answer choice there.

Comment: Is the ODE supposed to be $(1+t)y''+2y=0$? If not, could you be kind enough to explain why you multiplied $y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n t^n$ by $2$ in the second step?

Comment: You are right, that’s a typo. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

$$y(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n t^n$$

then

$$y''(t)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)c_n t^{n-2}$$

which is equivalent to

$$y''(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}t^n$$

so

\begin{align*}
(1+t)y''(t) &= y''(t)+ty''(t)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}t^n\right]+t\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}t^n\\
&= \left(2c_2+2\cdot 3c_3 t+3\cdot 4c_4 t^2+\cdots\right)+t\left(2c_2+2\cdot 3c_3 t+3\cdot 4c_4 t^2+\cdots\right)\\
&= \left(2c_2+2\cdot 3c_3 t+3\cdot 4c_4 t^2+\cdots\right)+\left(2c_2 t+2\cdot 3c_3 t^2+3\cdot 4c_4 t^3+\cdots\right)\\
&= \left(1\cdot 2c_2+0\cdot 1c_1\right)+\left(2\cdot 3c_3+1\cdot 2c_2\right)t+\left(3\cdot 4c_4+2\cdot 3c_3\right)t^2+\cdots\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}+n(n+1)c_{n+1}\right]t^n
\end{align*}

It follows that

\begin{align*}
0 &= (1+t)y''(t)+2y(t)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}+n(n+1)c_{n+1}\right]t^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2c_n t^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}+n(n+1)c_{n+1}+2c_n\right]t^n
\end{align*}

and upon equating coefficients,

$$(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+2}+n(n+1)c_{n+1}+2c_n=0$$

No initial conditions were given, so $c_0$ and $c_1$ can be chosen arbitrarily. The recurrence relation above then gives

\begin{align*}
c_2 &= -c_0\\
c_3 &= \frac{c_0-c_1}{3}\\
&\text{ }\vdots
\end{align*}

Thus,

$$y(t)=c_0+c_1 t-c_0t^2+\frac{c_0-c_1}{3}t^3+\cdots$$

so (d) is the correct answer.

**Edit**: I’m apparently blind! While writing this answer, I didn’t notice that (d) is the exact same series I derived. In light of this observation (thank you Carl!), I’ve edited out the last part of my original response, where I claimed that (b) was the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for the very good answer. However, the problem didn't include that $y(0)=0$. But if we assume that $y(0) \neq 0$, then the first 4 terms of the power series become. $c_0+c_1t-c_0t^2+\frac{c_0-c_1}{3}t^3$ which matches answer d).

Answer (score 3):

Take $t=0$. You get from the ODE $y^{\prime \prime}(0)+y(0)=0$.

And answer b) is the only valid option *providing that at least one is valid*.

Comment: I still have some doubts about this question. From A. E. Rosas' answer, he shows that the answer is actually d). However, your short answer says that b) is correct and it has gotten 4 upvotes. So which is correct?

Comment: you forgot the factor 2

Comment: @GCab at the time they wrote their answer, the OP had a typo: the ODE was written as $(1+t)y’’+y=0$, not $(1+t)y’’+2y=0$. It has since been corrected.